# want to compare a stored column values to some string

Tags: android, sqlite

> I just want to know how to get column value of one of my column
>   "STATUS" in order to compare it with string "c" and "s"  so respective
>   page can be displayed....!!!

```
    boolean validLogin = validateLogin(username, password, getApplicationContext());
   if(validLogin)
   {
       if(status=="s")

    Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), JSHomePage.class);
    in.putExtra("UserName", muname.getText().toString());
    startActivity(in);
       }
   else if(status=="c")
       {  Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CompView.class);
        in.putExtra("UserName", muname.getText().toString());
        startActivity(in);}
   }
```

> I have a table name login which has 3 field useranme,password and status..!!
>   here is edited code

```
  public void onClick(View v) 
 {
 switch(v.getId())
 {

 case R.id.register:
  Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Registration.class);
  startActivity(i);
  break;

 case R.id.login:

  muname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Ledituname);
  mpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Leditpw);

  String username = muname.getText().toString();
  String password = mpassword.getText().toString();



  if(username.equals("") || username == null)
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter User Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else if(password.equals("") || password == null)
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else
  {
   boolean validLogin = validateLogin(username, password, getApplicationContext());

   if(validLogin)
   {        
       if(status.equals("s"))
       {
    Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), JSHomePage.class);
    in.putExtra("UserName", muname.getText().toString());
    startActivity(in);
       }
       else if(status.equals("c"))
       {  Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CompView.class);
        in.putExtra("UserName", muname.getText().toString());
        startActivity(in);}
   }
  }
  break;

 }

 }


 private boolean validateLogin(String username, String password, Context baseContext) 
 {
  DB = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());
  SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getReadableDatabase();

  String[] columns = {"_id","status"};

  String selection = "username=? AND password=?";
  String[] selectionArgs = {username,password};

  Cursor cursor = null;
  try{

  cursor = db.query(DBHelper.Login_Table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

  startManagingCursor(cursor);

  }
  catch(Exception e)

  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

  if(numberOfRows <= 0)
  {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Name and Password miss match..\nPlease Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Login.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   return false;
  }
  status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status"));

  return true;

 }

 }
```

> New logcat

```
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.google.data.Login.validateLogin(Login.java:139)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.google.data.Login.onClick(Login.java:83)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-12 20:33:54.169: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Change order in `username.equals("") || username == null`, otherwise you'll get NPE in case `username == null`

Comment: @vlad: its working fine. . :-)

Comment: it means you always get empty string (""), but in case you happen to get `null` username, if will fail, so this is a bug-prone code. Fixing it is up to you. I'm just suggesting.

Comment: @vlad ohk.now i got it..thanxs..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

Create a class variable mStatus :

```
public String mStatus;
```

Add "STATUS" to your array of columns :

```
String[] columns = {"_id", "status"};
```

And just before returning true in your validateLogin method, put the status value in your mStatus class variable.

```
mStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status"));
```

Please note that your code is not what we can call a "clean code" so i give you a working solution not a "clean solution" i let you improve and clean your class ;-)

One more thing, in order to compare String value, you must use `myString.equals("myvalue")` and not `myString == "myvalue"`

finally you compare mStatus with "s" and "c"

```
if(validLogin)
   {
       if(mStatus=="s")
       {//System.out.println("In Valid");
....
```

Comment: hey thanxs . . .m new to android so . . .dnt knw much of it. . . . I have done wat u hv writen but now my avd is shuting down . . And why i have to declare string column .

Comment: can you copy past the content of your Logcat when your avd shutting down ? You have to declare all the colums you want to retrieve from the db.

Comment: i have edited the code check the logcat.and also did i putted status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status"));
in right place??

Comment: You should put this line before returning true. 
After this :
if(numberOfRows <= 0)
  {
......
  }
status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status"));

return true;

Comment: Add this line :
cursor.moveToFirst();
before 

status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status"));